# What is the name of the color wheel that a person can use to pick the logo color

Tags: color, logo

What is the name of the wheel used to pick the right colors for a logo to be an exact match

Comment: Chances are you are referring to the [Pantone](http://www.pantone.com) Matching System.

Answer (score 2):

That is just called a color wheel and when its interactive it is sometimes called a color picker or a color chart. Yes it is a great place to choose a color, but to Match Colors you should use the alpha numeric color codes so they will be exact.

[image]

If you have a logo and you want to match the color you must use the eye dropper tool. The eyedropper samples the color you clicked and loads it into fill so you can use it other places.

When you sample the logo color make note of the color values, you can record the CMYK, RGB, or my favorite as a web developer the Hexadecimal color code. This looks like this #A0A0A0, six letters or numbers after the hash sign. This code can refer to any color possible on a computer and if you have the code you can recreate the color anywhere, even in paint (there wil be some conversion).

There are many color wheels and color pickers online, if you search for those terms you will find them. Also Illustrator and Photoshop have great color pickers that give the color values, and they have the eyedropper tool.

[image]